# Elixir: start http server only for prometheus metrics

Tags: http, server, elixir, prometheus, metrics

I have following code:

```
defmodule MyApp.Http do
  use Application

  require Logger

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    MyApp.PlugPipelineInstrumenter.setup()
    MyApp.MetricsExporter.setup()

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Http.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link([], opts)
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.MetricsExporter do
  use Prometheus.PlugExporter
end

defmodule MyApp.PlugPipelineInstrumenter do
  use Prometheus.PlugPipelineInstrumenter
end
```

But it does nothing. When I add:

```
plug MyApp.MetricsExporter
plug MyApp.PlugPipelineInstrumenter
```

I get compilation error: `undefined function plug/1`. I use elixir 1.10.3. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Where are you putting the `plug MyApp.MetricsExporter`? That should go in your `MyApp.Endpoint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a hex package called [prometheus_sidecar](https://hexdocs.pm/prometheus_sidecar/overview.html) that creates a ranch server dedicated to prometheus (so you could run it in any elixir application) and wires up [prometheus_plugs](https://hex.pm/packages/prometheus_plugs) for you.

It leverages erlang's application start lifecycle so there is no required configuration, besides adding it as a library to your application.

Let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: You can view the source for an example of how to wire everything up [endpoint](https://github.com/spencerdcarlson/prometheus_sidecar/blob/master/lib/prometheus_sidecar/endpoint.ex), [plug_exporter](https://github.com/spencerdcarlson/prometheus_sidecar/blob/master/lib/prometheus_sidecar/plug_exporter.ex) Its not a traditional Phoenix endpoint because it's just simple ranch cowboy server, but it should be similar.